# aiohttp post request Worker crashed while servicing request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Here i am trying to collect the data from other web api source . but while i am running 4-5 task fetch_page in  parallel.

I am get "Worker crashed while servicing request"

please suggest me some way to get out of this issue.

Also i am receiving a large amount of data in response from aiohttp.post request , so sometimes write.write method is failing to write data to client side

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import re


def fetch_page(writer, url, data):
    response = yield from aiohttp.post(url,data=data)
    resp = yield from response.read_and_close() <== here some time i am getting "Worker crashed while servicing request" 
    writer.write(resp)  
    yield  # Yield to the event loop
    yield from writer.drain()
    return
```

Comment: 1. How did you get "Worker crashed while servicing request" message? The text is not part of aiohttp library.
2. `read_and_close()` is obsolete and deprecated. Use `.read()` instead.
If `.write()` failed you should close response in `except: ` block

Comment: i am running 5-6 fetch_page task in parallel for same url , but different data , and finally writing the o/p received  , in some case as a response from "response = yield from aiohttp.post(url,data=data)" i am receiving Worker crashed while servicing request.